# How do I use the transitions in Davinci Resolve 17?

Tags: video-editor, mp4, davinci-resolve, windows-movie-maker

This program stands in stark contrast of the simple but effective Windows Movie Maker of old, Davinci is not as 'simple' and it seems like it very 'complex' at times. One of the things that I liked about Windows Movie Maker is the ability to put in transitions on a timeline. While it is simple to do in Windows Movie Maker, it is not as easy in Resolve as Resolve is much more complex program. How do you put in transitions on a timeline? Can anyone explain this to me? I am not used to programs like these.

Answer (score 1):

You drag the transitions from the Toolbox in the Effects Library (Click the Effects Library at the top left of the Resolve interface if you don't see the Toolbox) over the two video clips.

One thing to keep in mind is that if you try and put a transition over two full clips (un-trimmed) Resolve won't allow it to be dropped. You can overcome this by trimming the end of the first clip and the beginning of the second clip.

Once they are clipped enough for resolve to do the transition you should be able to drag and drop the transition between the clips.

Comment: Also, Command/Ctrl-T will apply the default transition.